# Does this JSON configuration workflow have a name?

Tags: json

I have a system where we collect a lot of JSON configuration from different parties to configure our overall service.

The repository looks like a directory of formatted JSON files. For example `foo.json`:

```
{
  "id": "3bd0e397-d8cc-46ff-9e0d-26fa078a37f3",
  "name": "Example",
  "logo": "https://example/foo.png"
}
```

We have a pipeline whereby the owner of foo.json can overwrite this file by committing a new file at any time, since fast updates are required.

However we require unfortunately to skip whole files or override some values for various $reasons.

Hence we commit something like `touch foo.json.skip` when we want the file to be skipped before publishing. And similarly, we have a foo.json.d/override.json to perhaps override the logo because it's poorly formatted or something.

Is there a name for this sort of JSON pipeline that we have? It's inspired by systemd configuration, but maybe system configuration was inspired by something else?

Comment: [Infrastructure as Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrastructure_as_code)